# SonarQube 4.1.1 preferred to run using external database?

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

I installed a 3.x version of Sonar well over a year ago. Then, it was stated in some documentation that it is preferred to run Sonar using an external database and not use the default one. However, I cannot find this mentioned anywhere anyomore.

I would rahter not have the extra hassle of setting up e.g. MySQL, is it ok to use the internal DB for 3-4 code branches? I execute my Sonar runs using Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal database is designed to get Sonar up and running quickly. The following would be my reasons for not using it in production. (While I use MySQL similar features exist for other DB engines):

- MySQL supports replication. This enables the ability to maintain a warm stand-by of the production SonarQube server
- MySQL has excellent backup and recovery tools. This enables a sandbox (for developers to play with) and pre-production (test plugins and new versions of Sonar) instances of Sonar built from a automated backups of production.
- Scaling up a Sonar solution is challenging with embedded databases. MySQL has options for running in a clustered configuration (I haven't done this but useful option).
- Upgrading embedded databases is generally not as well supported. Running a popular DB engine means any upgrade issues are likely to be fixed quickly.

I would advise you to run a dedicated database engine if you value your historical metrics.

**Notes**

- Sonar used to run the [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) database and this was changed to the
  more capable [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) database. This may be the reason why the warning
  was removed (you'd have to ask SonarQube).
- MySQL is a very easy database to setup and maintain.

Comment: There is now a big warning that you can't miss on the web interface.

Comment: @DavidRACODON-SonarSource Haha there you go then!